# CollectionViewCell out of CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I implemented an animation that increases the scale of the chosen cell in the collection view, the problem is that when I increase it, the bounds of the collection view cover the cell.

The scenario I'm facing is this:

```
 BEFORE:               AFTER:
 ____________         ____________  
|  ___       |       |_____       |
| (___)      |       |     \      |
|____________|       |_____/______|
```

But this is what I want in fact:

```
 BEFORE:               AFTER:
 ____________         ____________  
|  ___       |      _|_____       |
| (___)      |     /       \      |
|____________|     \_______/______|
```

where the big rectangle is the collection view and the small figure, the collection view cell.

in a nutshell, I want it to be possible for the cell to appear outside the collection view.

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried `collectionView.clipsToBounds = false`?

Comment: lol you were 5 seconds earlier than me haha @ConnorNeville

Comment: thanks! it worked nice, matter of fact the cells that were hidden in the collection view are appearing now